# Laravel lighthouse 4.16 get current user without using @middleware which is deprecated

Tags: laravel-authentication, laravel-lighthouse

I have the following mutation

```
type Mutation {
  # ...

  createArticle(title: String!, content: String!): Article 
    @field(resolver: "ArticleMutator@create")
    
@middleware(checks: ["auth:api"]) // here is the problem related to relation of a user and an article
}
```

Using the @middleware directive can't be used anymore in Laravel Lighthouse 4.16

So I want to know which method can I use to retrieve the currently authenticated user and create a relation to an article at the same time?

Update full project here https://github.com/wolfiton/laravel-graphql

Also idon't know why I can't get the user.id from the context. I couldn't find anything related to this problem in the docs.

Here are the 2 files that are related to my problem

https://github.com/wolfiton/laravel-graphql/blob/master/graphql/schema.graphql

https://github.com/wolfiton/laravel-graphql/blob/master/app/GraphQL/Mutations/ArticleMutator.php

Error when using Matt Davenport suggestion @guard

```
type Mutation @guard(with: ["api"]) {
    createArticle(title: String!, content: String!): Article
        @field(resolver: "ArticleMutator")
}
```

```php
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "debugMessage": "Call to a member function articles() on null",
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "internal"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 6,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createArticle"
      ],
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@middleware` directive has been deprecated in favor of `@guard`, so I would do something like this:

```
type Mutation @guard(with: ["api"]) {
  createArticle(title: String!, content: String!): Article @field(resolver: "ArticleMutator@create")
}
```

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately.I will post all my code on GitHub and maybe if you have time you can tell me, why it doesn't work, because I tried everything I could and no result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it didn't work". Was there an error, or a result you weren't expecting?

Comment: Also when I first saw this error I checked my model relationships but they seem fine.I really don't know what is causing this problem. "Call to a member function articles() on null",

Comment: From the docs: 

> Note that @guard does not log in users. To ensure the user is logged in, add the AttemptAuthenticate middleware to your lighthouse.php middleware config.